# using google analytics to track user-wise information

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, matomo

What is the best option to track user wise analytics? I am looking for google analytics along with per-user reports.

some questions:
1) was using custom variables to track the userId and was able to see the report in Visitors -> 'Custom Variable', any way to see the same on the content report. There is an option for 'user defined variables' but that is not populated.
2) is there a sandbox for google analytics. searched for it but it seems like the only option is to serve the file from the local machine (to check the tracking gif) and to create a separate tracker so as to not pollute the production data with testing. The lack of sandbox seems kind of a PITA. can check the content report immediately but custom variables takes a longer time to get updated.
3) are http://piwik.org/[piwik.org](http://piwik.org/) or http://mnutt.github.com/hummingbird/[hummingbird](http://piwik.org/) any good?
4) what is the best way to track per-user interaction on the site, can suggest a better alternative to google analytics. Realtime is not a requirement. Wanted a hosted service as i do not want to host a server and also do not want to go into the trouble of parsing the logs - but can do it if it is easy.

Comment: I think you're going to run into privacy issues with this...

Comment: GA Terms of Service: "You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track or collect personally identifiable information of Internet users, nor will You (or will You allow any third party to) associate any data gathered from Your website(s) (or such third parties' website(s)) with any personally identifying information from any source as part of Your use (or such third parties' use) of the Service. " http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html

Comment: the "personally identifiable information" is in context of my database, it is my data and as such i am willing to risk it. The information is opaque.